# How to redirect requests to www.example.com/admin to different module in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework-modules

I have a problem with redirecting requests in my application.

My rules:

- **employer.domain.com** - should point to a page of the employer - uses **default** module
- **employer.domain.com/panel/** - should point to a administration page of specific employer - uses **dashboard** module
- **www.domain.com** - should point to page aggregating all employers - uses **default** module

I've tested a lot of different routes, but when one route is working, other get broken. Also often it works only for root paths, but when I add call to some controller and action - it crashes. Maybe I should write custom controller plugin? What do You think?

Here is my current configuration. It's a mess, but maybe it will help catching some silly mistake.

```
// employer.domain.com/panel
$pathRoute_panel = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':panel/:controller/:action/:id/',
    array(
        'panel' => '',
        'module' => 'dashboard',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'id' => '',
    ),
    array(
        'panel' => 'panel'
    )
);

$subdomainRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':employer.'.$config['host'],
    null,
    array(
        'employer' => '([a-z0-9]+)',
    )
);
$router->addRoute('employer_panel', $subdomainRoute->chain($pathRoute_panel));


// employer.domain.com - main employer page
$pathRoute_panel = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'vcard',
        'action' => 'index',
        'id' => '',
    )
);

$subdomainRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':employer.'.$config['host'],
    null,
    array(
        'employer' => '([a-z0-9]+)',
    )
);
$router->addRoute('employer_vcard', $subdomainRoute->chain($pathRoute_panel));


// domain.com/
$pathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
    ),
    $dispatcher,
    $request
);

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname($config['host']);
$router->addRoute('default', $route->chain($pathRoute));

// www.domain.com/
$pathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
    ),
    $dispatcher,
    $request
);

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('www.'.$config['host']);
$router->addRoute('default_www', $route->chain($pathRoute));
```

EDIT: This is my solution:

```
// employer.domain.com
$pathRoute_panel = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'vcard',
        'action' => 'index',
        'id' => '',
    )
);

$subdomainRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':employer.'.$config['host'],
    null,
    array(
        'employer' => '([a-z0-9]+)',
    )
);
$router->addRoute('employer_vcard', $subdomainRoute->chain($pathRoute_panel));

// employer.domain.com/panel/
$pathRoute_panel = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'panel/:controller/:action/:id/',
    array(
        'panel' => 'panel',
        'module' => 'dashboard',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'id' => '',
    )
);

$subdomainRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':employer.'.$config['host'],
    null,
    array(
        'employer' => '([a-z0-9]+)',
    )
);
$router->addRoute('employer_panel', $subdomainRoute->chain($pathRoute_panel));
```

Comment: With the routes you posted, which of them work as expected and which don't? Can you give an example URL for one which doesn't work when you add controller and action.

Comment: Works: employer.domain.com, employer.domain.com/panel/, domain.com
Not work: employer.domain.com/some-controller/some-action

Answer (score 0):

```
// Enforce Subdomain usage
// Will match employer.domain.com/*
$subdomainRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    'employer.'.$config['host'] . '/*'
);


// Will match /panel/{id, required}/{controller, optional}/{action, optional}/{further parameters, optional}
$pathRoute_panel = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'panel/:id/:controller/:action/*',
    array(
        'module' => 'dashboard',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '\d+'
    )
);

// employer.domain.com - main employer page
// will match everything not matched before!
$pathRoute_page = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '*',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'vcard',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);

// You can add several routes to one chain ;) The order does matter.
$subDomainRoute->chain($pathRoute_page);
$subDomainRoute->chain($pathRoute_panel);
$router->addRoute($subDomainRoute);
```

Annotations are in the code. You can use the wildcard (*) to match anything further! There's no need of the `default_www` route - this's just the default behaviour (the default route now will match every subdomain but employer as it is matched by the `subDomainRoute`).

Comment: I am now trying your solution.

PS. I knew that more than one route could be chained, but I was too scare to try ;)

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work for me. I rewrote your solution for my application and it could not redirect any URL. Below I post my solution, which seems to work.

Comment: @MaxBarnas: As you're not enforcing a specific subdomain, I guess it'll work for any subdomain.